# Printing with plotter in customized paper size using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, printing

A plotter in my office has a spool of paper with a dimension of 42x36 inches. I am trying to print something where the paper itself (not the map layout) is 36x30.

Can I customize the paper dimensions in ArcMap, Adobe Acrobat, or does it have to be done in the plotter itself?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it from ArcMap.

When you are in the page in print setup window there is a properties button next to the dropdown where you select the printer. This will open the printer setting window where you should be able to set up a personalized paper size (as this is printer setting you will get different setting and option depending on witch printer you choose so I can get more specific on how to do it).

[image]

[image]

for my workflow I print to PDF and thus use the Adobe PDF printer, it let me add personalized paper size with a custom name (I use the paper size as name like 36x30) and remember the custom size so I can reuse it in other project. For the printing part I use the Plotter print manager to print the PDF. this workflow let me print in any size supported by the plotter.

Comment: This is the workflow I have been trying to do, but I cannot find anywhere in Adobe that allows you to customize the paper size. Can you show me the window that allows you to do that?

Comment: @matthiastrek I edited my answer with picture of setting windows for my Adobe PDF printer (in french but it should be identical in other languages)

Comment: Also if your question is now reduced to "how define custom page size for Adobe PDF printer"  GIS SE is not the best place to get answer....

Comment: I get a different window when I hit the properties button.

Comment: The window you get will depend on your operating system and the version of your printer driver. As I said before you are more likely to find how to define custom page size for your version of the PDF printer on some adobe help page than here